# A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression Error

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

Appointment:
API Name
Appointment__c
[image]

Doctor:
API Name
Doctors__c

**I am trying to list all the records of the selected doctor**

```
public class AppointmentsController {

private List<Doctors__c>doctorList = new List<Doctors__c>();
private List<Patient__c>patientList = new List<Patient__c>();
private List<Appointment__c>appointmentList = new List<Appointment__c>();
public Doctors__c selectedDoctor {get;set;}
public Patient__c selectedPatient {get;set;}
public  List<Appointment__c>doctorAppointmentsList{get;set;}
public DateTime appointmentDate {
    get{
        return appointmentDate;  
    }
    set;
}
public Id selectedDoctorId{
    get;
    set{
       selectedDoctorId=value;
       updateDoctor();
       updateAppointments();
       }
}
public AppointmentsController (){
newAppointment=new Appointment__c();
patientList =[SELECT Id,Name FROM Patient__c ORDER BY Name ASC];   
doctorList = [SELECT Id,Name,Working_Hours_Start__c,Working_Hours_End__c FROM Doctors__c ORDER BY Name ASC];
appointmentList=[SELECT Id,Name,Doctor__c,Appointment_Date__c,Duration_in_minutes__c,Patient__c FROM Appointment__c ORDER BY Name ASC];    
selectedDoctor =  doctorList[0];
selectedPatient= patientList[0];
}
private void updateAppointments()
{
    for(Appointment__c appointment :  appointmentList) {
       
              if(selectedDoctorId==appointment.Doctor__c.Id)
              {
                doctorAppointmentsList.add(appointment);
              }

    }
}
private void updateDoctor()
{
    for(Doctors__c doctor :  doctorList) {
       
              if(this.selectedDoctorId==doctor.Id)
              {
                selectedDoctor=doctor;
              }

    }
}
```

updateAppointments() error in this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend completing the module [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database) on Trailhead. Two of the units in that module cover how to query and access data across relationships.

However, in this case, you don't need to traverse a relationship at all.

```
appointment.Doctor__c.Id
```

should simply be replaced by

```
appointment.Doctor__c
```

The relationship field itself contains the related record Id.

---

This code is at risk of a number of governor limits problems (in particular the [Visualforce view state limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_visualforce_best_practices.meta/salesforce_visualforce_best_practices/pages_best_practices_perf_code_view_state.htm)), as well as general poor performance, due to:

- executing and storing unfiltered queries, which return all records in the database.
- performing filtering in Apex instead of appropriately filtering SOQL queries to show relevant data.

I would recommend you consider removing your unfiltered queries and rebuilding `updateDoctor()` to perform a new SOQL query when the selected doctor changes to acquire the doctor record and their appointments, using a parent-child relationship query (covered in the module linked above). You would then be able to remove `updateAppointments()` entirely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have to display the records on the apex page in accordance with the selected doctor and since the request is quite costly, I decided to filter in the controller

Comment: @Vanya I am recommending you filter _in SOQL_, not in Apex.